# puppeteer - first call to browser.newPage super slow

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Using puppeteer@2.1.1

The first call to browser.newPage() takes a long time ( approx 5 secs ), after that all the new page spawns take roughly 50ms

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    console.time('Browser');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: [
            '--headless',
            '--hide-scrollbars',
            '--mute-audio',
            '-no-sandbox'
        ]
    });
    console.timeEnd('Browser');

    console.time('Incognito');
    let context  = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    console.timeEnd('Incognito');

    console.time('Page');
    let page = await context.newPage('https://wl.postando.de/preview-front/432');
    console.timeEnd('Page');

    console.time('Page 1');
    page = await browser.newPage();
    console.timeEnd('Page 1');

    console.time('Page 2');
    page = await browser.newPage();
    console.timeEnd('Page 2');

    console.time('goto')
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    console.timeEnd('goto');

    console.time('Generate')
    await page.pdf({
        path: 'hn.pdf',
        format: 'letter'
        });
    console.timeEnd('Generate');

    await browser.close();
})();
```

The output :

> Browser: 107.656ms
>
> Incognito: 1.247ms
>
> Page: 5147.028ms
>
> Page 1: 35.273ms
>
> Page 2: 36.787ms
>
> goto: 773.726ms
>
> Generate: 78.117ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution - use `xvfb-run`

`xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" node pdf.js`